# TransactionRolledbackLocalException

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6

I'm having an annoying error message while trying to insert new element   in a one to many relationship using JPA 2.0.

```
public class Ordinateur implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Column(name = "TAG")
private BigInteger tag;
@Size(max = 30)
@Column(name = "MACHINE")
private String machine;
@Size(max = 25)
@Column(name = "NOM_FABRIQUANT")
private String nomFabriquant;
@Column(name = "NUM_SERIE")
private BigInteger numSerie;
@Column(name = "ADRESSE_IP")
private BigInteger adresseIp;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "NUM_SEQ")
private BigInteger numSeq;
@Size(max = 30)
@Column(name = "SYSTEME_EXPLOITATION")
private String systemeExploitation;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 30)
@Column(name = "IDORD")
private String idord;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idord")
private List<Systemeexploitation> systemeexploitationList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idord")
private List<Intervention> interventionList;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idord")
private List<Inventaire> inventaireList;

public Ordinateur() {
} //...........
```

my session bean :

```
         public void ordCreer(Ordinateur ordinateur) {
         ordinateurFacade.create(ordinateur);
        }
```

Managed Bean :

```
       public String enregistrerOrd() throws  Exception{
       manager.ordCreer(ordinateur);
       return "OrdList";
       }
```

and here's the error :

```
          ATTENTION: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrdinateurFacade, method: public void ejb.AbstractFacade.create(java.lang.Object)
          ATTENTION: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
at $Proxy312.create(Unknown Source)
at ejb.__EJB31_Generated__OrdinateurFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
     //...
     Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
     //...
     TTENTION: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Manager, method: public void DAO.Manager.ordCreer(jpa.Ordinateur)
       ATTENTION: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2314)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2096)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
at $Proxy312.create(Unknown Source)
at ejb.__EJB31_Generated__OrdinateurFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)

    //................
    Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
... 80 more
      Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:90)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:62)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:698)
```

I tryed to delete the @NotNull but nothing happened 
Any idea of the reason?

Comment: First, I would change the question, the real exception is the `ConstraintValidationException`. The others only signal that it happened in the middle of a transaction. Second, you say that you deleted the `@NotNull`, but are you sure it has been changed in the database schema?

Comment: Get the cause of the exception and print its embedded ConstraintViolations, as told in the exception message. You can also look at it from your debugger. That will tell you which of the many validation annotations is causing the problem. ANother way is to look at the data and see which property is not acceptable. Also, please, ad some empty lines between the properties in your code. It's very hard to read as is.

Comment: Did you assign the ID field? `@Id` implies `@NotNull`.